# Has anybody seen anything this expression before?

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics, finance

Suppose that $z(\cdot)$ is the demand function of an individual (consumer/investor) and $p$ is the price of the commodity/asset demanded. Does anybody know what is the intuition behind the following expression?
\begin{align}pz^{'}(p)+z(p)\end{align}

It seems to me like the derivative of $(pz(p))^{'}$ with respect to $p$. What is the intuition behind this? Has anybody seen anything this expression before?

Comment: Marginal revenue

Comment: Thank you @Herr K. My mind has stuck! You are absolutely right!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$p\cdot z(p)$ is total revenue (price times quantity), and so its derivative $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dp}pz(p)=pz'(p)+z(p)$ is marginal revenue.

Answer (score 2):

You're correct. Many useful things can be shown by taking this derivative.

Perhaps you were confused because you are used to solving for quantity rather than price - in which case you are more likely to take the derivative of R = z * p(z) with respect to z which gives you p(z) + z * dp(z)/dz